# Easy way to do Google searches with input text and checkboxes?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking for a simple way to do multiple Google searches based on a string I put in. That string will then be searched along with whatever checkboxes I tick. An example:

Input field:

> Stack Overflow

Checkboxes:

> [x] "CSS|HTML"
>
> [ ] "Javascript"
>
> [x] "C++|C#"|".Net"

Clicking a link/button to do the search will run these separate Google search queries (including the quotation marks and vertical bars):

> "Stack Overflow" "CSS|HTML"
>
> "Stack Overflow" "C++|C#"|".Net"

Could I do this in one page? It seems like it would be a simple solution but I'm not sure how to make it (just assuming HTML or Javascript here). Any direction on where to start would be great.

Comment: ok, look this fiddle example and then try research what is done in code : https://jsfiddle.net/qzta7dxe/2/ (updated with some simple explanation)

Comment: @nelek Thank you! Is there a way to make it open each search in a separate window? Right now if you check Javascript and CSS/HTML it searches `"input" "Javascript" "CSS/HTML"` and not `"input" "Javascript"` and `"input" "CSS/HTML"` separately. I tried to add the window.open under each If statement and edit the variable names but it didn't work.

Comment: code provided in answer ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google search will open separately window/tab for each checked option.

There is example (similar like in comment) [`fiddle example`](https://jsfiddle.net/qzta7dxe/6/)

html :

```
<input type="text" id="src" value="" placeholder="For what You search?" />
<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="o1"/><label for="o1">CSS/HTML<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="o2"/><label for="o2">Javascript<br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="o3"/><label for="o2">C++/C#/.NET<br><br>
    <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="start();" />
```

js :

```
    function start() {
    // every text must be encoded using encodeURIComponent

    //store search string into variable called src
    var src='https://www.google.com/search?q=\"' + encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById('src').value)+'\"+';

    // check 1st checkbox - if is checked add to src variable CSS|HTML
    if(document.getElementById('o1').checked) {
        var src1 = src + '\"'+ encodeURIComponent('CSS|HTML')+'\"';
        window.open(src1,'_blank');
    }

    // check 2nd checkbox - if is checked add to src variable Javascript
    if(document.getElementById('o2').checked) {
        var src2 = src + '\"'+ encodeURIComponent('Javascript')+'\"';
        window.open(src2,'_blank');
    }

    // check 3th checkbox - if is checked add to src variable "C++|C#" ".NET"
    if(document.getElementById('o3').checked) {
        var src3 = src + '\"'+ encodeURIComponent('C++|C#')+'\"+\"'+encodeURIComponent('.NET')+'\"';
        window.open(src3,'_blank');
    }
}
```